# name_scope of Tensorflow not work in Tensorboard

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

```
Settings:
Mac OS 10.14.6
Python 3.7.4
Tensorflow 2.0.0
```

I have a problem when it comes to name_scope settings.
I write `name_scope()` in my code, but it has no name_scope in  Tensorboard like [this image in Tensorboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8Fki.png).
I intended to make a name scope for Flatten, Dense, and so on in this image.

I uninstalled and re-install Tensorflow, but I got same result.
As additional information, I do not get any errors in Terminal.
Do someone have any idea for this situation?

```
def _model_B0001(self):
    with tf.name_scope('1stLayer'):
        inputs = Input(self.shape)
        x = Flatten()(inputs)
        x = Dense(512)(x)
        output1 = Dense(self.nb_classes1, activation='softmax', name='output1')(x)
        output2 = Dense(self.nb_classes2, activation='softmax', name='output2')(x)
        predictions = [output1, output2]
    model = Model(inputs, predictions)
    model.compile(loss={'output1': 'categorical_crossentropy',
                        'output2': 'categorical_crossentropy'},
                  optimizer='adam',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
    model.summary()
    with open(self.summary_txt, "w") as fp:
        model.summary(print_fn=lambda x: fp.write(x + "\r\n"))
    return model
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by myself.
It maybe because of collision of pip and anaconda.
So I did below.

1. Uninstall all pip package.

   ```
    $ pip freeze > piplist.txt
    $ sudo pip uninstall -r piplist.txt
   ```
2. Uninstall all anaconda package.

Uninstall pakages.

```
    $ conda install anaconda-clean
    $ anaconda-clean
```

Delete empty folders after the pakages being deleted.

```
    $ rm -fr ~/.anaconda_backup
    $ rm -fr /anaconda3
```

Erase the content in .bash_profile

```
    $ sudo nano .bash_profile
```

3. Re-install anaconda. Download from https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/
4. Re-run tensorboard.

   ```
   def _model_A0001(self):
    with tf.name_scope('1stLayer') as scope:
       # print(scope)
       # sys.exit()
       inputs = Input(self.shape)
       x = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), border_mode='same', name='conv2d')(inputs)
       x = Activation('relu', name='relu')(x)
       x = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), name='max_pooling')(x)
       x = Dropout(0.25, name='dropout')(x)

    with tf.name_scope('2ndLayer'):
       x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), border_mode='same')(x)
       x = Activation('relu')(x)
       x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3))(x)
       x = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(x)
       x = Dropout(0.25)(x)

    with tf.name_scope('DenseLayer'):
       x = Flatten()(x)
       x = Dense(512)(x)
       x = Activation('relu')(x)
       x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
       output1 = Dense(self.nb_classes1, activation='softmax', name='output1')(x)
       output2 = Dense(self.nb_classes2, activation='softmax', name='output2')(x)
       predictions = [output1, output2]
       # inputs = [inputs, inputs]
       model = Model(inputs, outputs=predictions)
       model.compile(loss={'output1': 'categorical_crossentropy',
                           'output2': 'categorical_crossentropy'},
                     optimizer='adam',
                     metrics=['accuracy'])
    model.summary()
    with open(self.summary_txt, "w") as fp:
       model.summary(print_fn=lambda x: fp.write(x + "\r\n"))
    return model
   ```

[image]